# HTML table by javascript is appended all at the same time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In the following [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zHaU3/2/), everything gets appended at the same time. What I really want is for each part of content to be appended one at a time.

I've tried using `setTimeout` but it doesn't work. Any help on this one?

---

**HTML**

```
<body>
<div id="first"></div>
<table id="second"></table>
</body>
```

**JS**

```
function show(exampler){

    var tbody = document.createElement("tbody"),
    tr = document.createElement("tr");

    tr.innerHTML = exampler.test + " " exampler.id;
    tbody.appendChild(tr);

    $(tbody).hide().prependTo("#second").fadeIn(1000);
}

var content = [{"test":"just a test","id":1},
               {"test":"just a test","id":2},
               {"test":"just a test","id":3},
               {"test":"just a test","id":4}];

content.forEach(function(inside){
        show(inside);
});
```

**CSS**

```
#second{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: there is no link to the fiddle.

Comment: Please add the link to your fiddle and also post the relevant code in the question itself.

Comment: You haven't linked a fiddle. Also, please put the relevant code here and then link to the fiddle

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because questions about code you have written must include the relevant code **in the question itself**, along with a clear description of what's expected, what's happening instead, and why that surprises you.

Comment: I've taken a look at the fiddle and updated it. Simply click on the link you provided to see my fixes. :-)

Comment: This is your **19th** question. You really should know how things work by now, especially how to use the preview area, to include code in the question, and how to link.

Comment: If you paste your code here and edit your post so the link is actually a link, your question can be reopened.

Comment: Updated, i'm sorry for the trouble, been offsleeping for a long time.

Comment: Here's one solution, which I can't submit until the question's reopened: http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/w6LkJ/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one solution. I used `$.each` as the easiest way to pass a counter to the function, and then `.delay`ed the `.fadeIn` of each element by that many seconds.

```
$.each(content, function (i,el) {
    show(i,el);
});

function show(i,exampler) {
    var tbody = document.createElement("tbody"),
        tr = document.createElement("tr");
    tr.innerHTML = exampler.test + " " + exampler.id;
    tbody.appendChild(tr);

    $(tbody).hide().appendTo("#second").delay(i*1000).fadeIn(1000);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/w6LkJ/

There are ways to optimize and/or shorten this; I tried to make as few changes to your original code as possible.

Comment: I'm not understanding how the "i" interacts with the program, would you care to explain it to me please? :)

Comment: Since all the `tbody`s are appended within milliseconds of each other, `.delay(i*1000)` makes the first one fade in right away (`i=0`), the second one fade in after one second, the third after two seconds, etc.

Comment: hey, sorry to disturb you again, but would you be so kind as to tell me what would be the most beneficial way to optimize this? I've figured it out some time ago but I'm in doubt wether what implementation I should use.

Comment: That depends on your goal. The most efficient code to run uses no jQuery at all, but jQuery does make the code shorter and easier to read. This is a question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com if you really want help with it.